# Bot Channel Registration Cortana MSA

Tags: azure, botframework, cortana

After creating a bot, I also wanted to publish the bot as skill to cortana.

When trying to go into the Azure Portal and setting up a Bot Channel Registration accordingly I got the info, that this is not possible via an account connected to Azure Active Directory: [image: Cortana only support via MSA]

I set up a private Microsoft Account (outlook.com) and created a trial subscription in Azure. Unfortunately when I set up a Bot Channel Registration there Cortana is not avaible as channel to add: [image: Cortana not available]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cortana is being scaled back by the Cortana Team. High-level points of interest are:

- Consumer-facing Cortana services have been deprecated by the Cortana team. This means it is no longer possible to create a new bot and set it up to use the Cortana channel.
- On September 7th, all consumer-facing Cortana services will be shut off. This means existing bots will no longer work with Cortana.
- After September 7th, Cortana will only be a Windows and Enterprise-level product and will only work with AAD.

You can read more about the shift in service availability [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4575625/upcoming-changes-to-cortana).